# prevent conversion of one-column matrix to numeric?

Tags: r, types, matrix

Here is my problem:

```
gg <- matrix(0,4,4)
class(gg)
class(gg[,1])
```

R is being a little too helpful here; I'd prefer that the one-column matrix stayed a matrix.  This works, but it gets expensive:

```
class(t(t(gg[,1])))
```

And this works, but it seems like it shouldn't have to be necessary:

```
class(matrix(gg[,1], ncol=1))
```

Can you recommend a nice alternative, as brainless, effortless, and costless as possible?

Comment: my bad.  Your answer was fast and right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the argument `drop = FALSE`:

```
gg[, 1, drop = FALSE]
#      [,1]
# [1,]    0
# [2,]    0
# [3,]    0
# [4,]    0

class(gg[,1, drop = FALSE])
# [1] "matrix"
```